# Command key to Meta in Emacs

Tags: linux, macos, emacs, keyboard

I'm using a Mac keyboard on Ubuntu at work. What do I add to my .emacs file to turn the command key to Meta?
I tried `(setq mac-command-key-is-meta t)` and `(setq mac-command-key 'meta)` and neither works.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried

(setq mac-command-modifier 'meta)

Answer (score 1):

I think in Ubunto, your best bet may be to just use xkeymaps to re-define the key in the first place... because you kind of want that key to be meta for everything... I'd just do it globally.

Neither of those variables exist in emacs. You should probably do a C-h v variable name before you bother trying to use a variable...

However, mac-keyboard-modifier-mask-alist seems like it might be what you are looking for.  I would swap the option and command values and see if it does what you want.

Comment: For various reasons I don't want to do it globally. So I'm only looking for ways of how to do it in Emacs.

Turns out these variables exist only on OS X versions of Emacs.
http://www.mail-archive.com/emacs-pretest-bug@gnu.org/msg01743.html
C-h v says nothing about the variable that you mention either on Emacs23.

Comment: I'm running OSX... what emacs are you running? I notice that I'm running v 22.1 so, I'm way behind the times...

Comment: 23.1 on ubuntu 10.04 (the latest available from synaptic)